# Assembly with arrays

Tags: assembly

I am learning assembly and i am trying to make a script where it adds the elements in the array and then stores it in the last element in the array, however  i am getting this error

line 12: Runtime exception at 0x00400028: address out of range 0x10400000

Can anyone tell me what i have incorrect?

```
     .text
    .globl main

main:   la $t0, i
    la $s0, sum 
    la $t3, array 
    la $t5, k 
    addi $t0,$zero,0
    addi $s1,$zero,0

Loop:    
    lw $t1, 0($t3)  #loads first element in $t1
    add $s0,$s0,$t1 # add element in t1 with sum
    addi $t0,$t0,1 #add 1 to i
    addi $t3,$t3,4 # add 4 to a[i]
    bne $t0,$t5,Loop #if i ==k end
    sw $s0, 12($t3) #stores sum in last element
    nop

    .data 0x10010000
i:  .word 0
k:  .word 2
sum:    .word 0
array:  .word 0, 1, 4
```

Comment: I don't see any loop in your code. Did you mean to have one? And you're never increasing `$t3`. Also, the line `add $s0,$s0,$t1` looks incorrect (think about what `$s0` contains initially).

Comment: @Michael I have done some revisions, can you verify it?